# How to Set a Filter through FileChooser class?

Tags: java, xml, filechooser

```
class Myfilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
{
      public boolean accept(File file) 
      {
            String filename = file.getName();
            return filename.endsWith(".xml");
      }
      public String getDescription() 
      {
            return "*.xml";
      }
}
```

Comment: `myJFileChooser.setFileFilter(new Myfilter())`?

Answer (score 1):

By calling the [`setFileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) method.

E.g., in your code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new Myfilter());
```

Answer (score 1):

calling set filter may not work here ,
I got the better solution by below code

```
FileNameExtensionFilter("XML","xml","xml&XML"));
```